# list in redis all active/subscribed channels

Tags: redis, command, key, channel

I am new to redis

I am trying to list all the subscribed channels

is there a command to do that?

the other possibility is to store in a key the channels but I am sure there must be some other way

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't state it explicitly, I assume that you're interested in the channels that a specific client is subscribed to. Unfortunately, there isn't a Redis command for that and you'll need to keep track of it yourself (e.g. with a key as you had suggested).